# Online Accounts blank after upgrade

Tags: 12.10, online-accounts

After upgrading from 12.04 to 12.10 I got all entries of Online Accounts blank.

I tried to uninstall and reinstall `gnome-control-center-signon`, but no luck. Is there any way to fix it or at least clear all the entries so I can add them again? I cannot add new entries either, because the option list for account type is also empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, I solved by installing the "handler" suitable for all accounts that I had before upgrading. Search in synaptic: `gwibber-service-name`, something like `gwibber-service-twitter` and install those that are needed.